# JENKINS 100% CPU LOAD

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a 4 core centos server where Jenkins is hosted. All four cores are showing 100% utilised.

1. I restarted Jenkins - Didn't fix it.
2. I stopped Jenkins - Did'nt fix.
3. I cleared all existing builds and Hit "Reload Configuration from Disk" - Didn't fix
4. I installed "Discard Old Build plugin" - Didn't fix.

[image]

Is there anything else I can try? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the instance seemed to fix the issue. However I still do not know for sure what was causing it. The removal of old build could've aided as well.